# displaying data order by category php

Tags: php

How can i display

```
category1

id
title

category2

id
title
```

but until now only I can display is all of them order by category.my code:

```
 $query = mysql_query("select * from article where user_id = '$userId' order by category,date desc") ; 
 while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query )) {
    $id=$row['id'];
    $trimstring = substr($row['body'], 0, 100) ;
    $varCategory = NULL;
        ?>
        <div class="container" id = "articles">
            <h1><a href="index.php?page=articol&id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></a></h1>
            <p>  <?php echo $trimstring; ?> </p>
            <p id = "date">  <?php echo $row['date']; ?> </p>
        </div>

       <?php
         }
```

Comment: What is query here ?

Comment: $query = mysql_query("select * from article where user_id = '$userId' order by category,date desc") ;

Comment: Just an advise, don't use mysql API anymore, this is obslolet and remove in the last version of PHP, see PDO or Mysqli

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: how can i display the name of the category and then the items with his categories and so on?

Comment: echo $row['category'] doesn't work?

Comment: `<?php
 $query = mysql_query("select * from article where user_id = '$userId' order by category,date desc") ; 
 $category_data = array();
 while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query )) {
    $category_data[$row['category']] = $row;
 }
?>
<?php foreach($category_data as $key=>$value){?>       
    <div class="container" id = "articles">
        <h1>Category is :- <?php echo $key;?></h1>
        <p>Title is:-<a href="index.php?page=articol&id=<?php echo $value['id'];?>"><?php echo $value['title'];?></a></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>` something like this. change accordingly.